# used exactextract to extract values from RasterLayer, am confused on how to use what I got

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a dataframe with geo-tagged points (df_points), and a raster layer (raster). The bands of the raster have values of 1's (flooding / water) or 0's (no flooding / water).

```
summary(raster)
                 flood_extent_incl_permwater_20190625
Min.                                                0
1st Qu.                                             0
Median                                              0
3rd Qu.                                             0
Max.                                                1
NA's                                                0
```

Because there's a bit of fuzziness both with exactly where the points are, and where the edges of the raster layer are, I buffered the points into polygons and used exact_extract to get what I think is supposed to be "Sum of defined raster values within the polygon, accounting for coverage fraction", based on [this documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/exactextractr/readme/README.html).

```
df_points_buffer <- st_buffer(df_points, dist = 200)
b.rasValue <- exact_extract(raster, df_points_buffer, function(values, coverage_fraction)
  sum(coverage_fraction))
```

However, when I tabled the results what I have is a bunch of 0's (makes sense, may polygons will be completely in areas without flooding), and values that run up to 314.0etc.something.

options(digits=10)
summary(b.rasValue)

```
  Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max.
```

0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   9.908810   1.710935 314.015738

hist(b.rasValue)
[image]

What I'd really like to actually get to is a 0-1 range based on what percentage of the polygon has 1 value. So, like in the diagram image below, the 1 polygon would have a value of 1, the 3 a value of 0, and the 2 a value around .6.

[image]

Is there a way to convert the information to understand it in that way? I'd really love to not rerun an extract function, because I have 20mil observations and it takes forever (yes, I should have done a test chunk). I think (?) I would just need to divide it by the possible maximum, but, honestly, I'm not entirely sure I am correctly understanding the process that is going on and wanted to check in here. Thanks!

Comment: interesting problem - similar to what i had to do last year.  did it with qgis/grass gis zonal statistics in the end, maybe that is also an option for you? if not - can you give us some test data to experiment? else i am afraid it will be difficult to help.

Comment: If your values are 0 or 1, doesn't `fun = 'mean'` give you the flooded fraction?